# -lm Not linking math library in makefile

Tags: c, unix, gcc, makefile

I know this error has been beaten to death, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I have linked my makefile below:

```
all: gensine info cs229towav

encode.o: encode.h encode.c
    gcc -c encode.c

write.o: write.c write.h
    gcc -c write.c

gensine.o: encode.c gensine.h gensine.c helper.c write.c
    gcc -c gensine.c -lm

helper.o: helper.c helper.h
    gcc -c helper.c

read.o: read.h read.c
    gcc -c read.c

info.o:read.c info.h info.c decode.c
    gcc -c info.c

decode.o: decode.c decode.h helper.c
    gcc -c decode.c

cs229towav.o: write.c read.c cs229towav.c cs229towav.h helper.c decode.c encode.c
    gcc -c cs229towav.c -lm

gensine: encode.o gensine.o write.o helper.o
    gcc -o gensine encode.o gensine.o write.o helper.o -lm

info: read.o info.o decode.o helper.o
    gcc read.o info.o decode.o helper.o

cs229towav: write.o read.o cs229towav.o decode.o encode.o helper.o
    gcc -o write.o read.o cs229towav.o decode.o encode.o helper.o -lm

Clean:
    rm -rf *o gensine info cs229towav
```

When I run a command such as "make gensine" I am returned with the following result:

```
>cc gensine.c -o gensine
/tmp/ccojm09X.o: In function `encodeCsFormat':
gensine.c:(.text+0x4b1): undefined reference to `sin'
/tmp/ccojm09X.o: In function `encodeWavFormat':
gensine.c:(.text+0xa39): undefined reference to `sin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After reading this is says undefined reference to sin, which is with the math library. Those functions listed are in the "encode.c" file which are included in the "gensine.c" file.

Comment: That output fragment doesn't seem to correspond to the makefile above, are you sure make is picking up the right makefile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command in the makefile:

```
gcc -o gensine encode.o gensine.o write.o helper.o -lm
```

does not match the command you printed at the end:

```
cc gensine.c -o gensine
```

Notice also that there is no `-lm`

Note that `make` knows how to make object files so you don't need most of the makefile.  Try this (remember to indent with TABs):

```
.PHONY : all clean
all = gensine info
CFLAGS =-Wall
LIBS = -lm

gensine: encode.o gensine.o write.o helper.o 
       gcc -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

info: read.o info.o decode.o helper.o
       gcc -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

cs229towav: write.o read.o cs229towav.o decode.o encode.o helper.o
       gcc -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

clean:
       rm -rf *.o gensine info cs229towav
```

Edit:

Boddie, note that your confusion arose because you thought the makefile was a script - ie. that you were running your script named `make` when you typed `make gensine`. In fact `make` is a command like `gcc` somewhere else in the filesystem (on Linux etc, type `which make` to see where it is). The `make` command expects to find an input file containing build rules called `makefile` or `Makefile` in the current directory.  If it doesn't find that file it uses some built-in rules instead - hence the `cc gensine.c -o gensine` which is nowhere in your makefile.  If you want to, you can tell `make` the name of the makefile (so that it doesn't use the default names) with the `-f` switch, as @DanielFischer described in the comments.

Comment: I use the file, and I get the same error as before. It is also the same output from the compiler

Comment: what did you call the makefile?  Do you have more than one makefile i the directory?

Comment: i named it "make" with no extension, and then I called "make gensine"

Comment: OMG wow!! I did not realize that the name mattered there. Thank you so much!

Comment: @boddie Or call it `make -f make gensine`. If you give your Makefiles non-standard names, you must tell `make` which file to use. In your case, since it didn't find one of the standard names, it used a baked-in rule, oops.

Comment: `make` recognizes the special variable `LDLIBS`. You could have used it and specified `LDLIBS=-lm`. This would have got you out of using `gcc -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)`.